# Magento 1.9 Custom Module submenu

Tags: php, magento

I would like to add one more item to my module and I would like some help

I used the module creator, to create this module, but I can't add one more item to my module

I edit this post to show my adminhtml.xml and my config.xml

Now I have both menus, but when I click, the page is all white, it seems that lost the route, I don't know where the problem is

[Magento Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wutua.png)

adminhtml.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <configuracao module="configuracao">
            <title>Zeepi Configuração</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <first_menu_child module="configuracao">
                    <title>Banner Principal</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>configuracao/adminhtml_configuracao</action>
                </first_menu_child>
                <second_menu_child module="configuracao">
                    <title>Banner Principal 2</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>configuracao/adminhtml_configuracao</action>
                </second_menu_child>
            </children>
        </configuracao>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <Zeep_Configuracao>
                        <title>Configuracao Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <children>
                             <first_menu_child module="configuracao">
                                <title>Banner Principal</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>configuracao/adminhtml_configuracao</action>
                            </first_menu_child>
                            <second_menu_child module="configuracao">
                                <title>Banner Principal 2</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <action>configuracao/adminhtml_configuracao</action>
                            </second_menu_child>
                        </children>
                    </Zeep_Configuracao>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
            <updates>
                <configuracao>
                    <file>configuracao.xml</file>
                </configuracao>
            </updates>
        </layout>
</config>
```

My config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Zeep_Configuracao>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Zeep_Configuracao>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <configuracao>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Zeep_Configuracao</module>
                    <frontName>configuracao</frontName>
                </args>
            </configuracao>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <configuracao>
                    <file>configuracao.xml</file>
                </configuracao>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <configuracao>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Zeep_Configuracao</module>
                    <frontName>configuracao</frontName>
                </args>
            </configuracao>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <global>
        <models>
            <configuracao>
                <class>Zeep_Configuracao_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>configuracao_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </configuracao>
            <configuracao_mysql4>
                <class>Zeep_Configuracao_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <configuracao>
                        <table>configuracao</table>
                    </configuracao>
                </entities>
            </configuracao_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <configuracao_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Zeep_Configuracao</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </configuracao_setup>
            <configuracao_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </configuracao_write>
            <configuracao_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </configuracao_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <configuracao>
                <class>Zeep_Configuracao_Block</class>
            </configuracao>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <configuracao>
                <class>Zeep_Configuracao_Helper</class>
            </configuracao>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Caany one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Am i right, that you want to add more menu points to the admin structure?

If so, your xml is your config.xml right? You should make some changes

**First:**
Magento supports a specific file for admin menu and ACL structure

your etc folder currently has a config.xml. Add a new file called adminhtml.xml with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <module_menu_name module="module_name">
            <title>Menu Point Title</title>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order> <!-- an int to position it in the menu -->
            <children>
                <first_menu_child module="module_name">
                    <title>Menu Child Name</title>
                    <action>module/action/child</action>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                </first_menu_child>
                <second_menu_child module="module_name">
                    <title>Second Menu Child Name</title>
                    <action>module/action/child2</action>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                </second_menu_child>
            </children>
        </module_menu_name>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <module_menu_name module="module_name">
                        <title>Menu Point Title</title>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <first_menu_child module="module_name">
                                <title>Menu Child Name</title>
                                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            </first_menu_child>
                            <second_menu_child module="module_name">
                                <title>Second Menu Child Name</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            </second_menu_child>
                        </children>
                    </module_menu_name>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Remove your code from config.xml

This should add an menu point with 2 submenu points. If you need further help, do not hesitate to ask

Comment: Work! but i lost Route, when i click, i get blank page :(

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Probably your routing (admin routes) are configured wrong. Can you post config.xml and adminhtml.xml?

Comment: you need to adjust the children and the corresponding controller actions